# do I need French export compliance approval to submit an iOS app that uses encryption?

Tags: iphone, ios, encryption, export, appstore

My company just (5th July 2011) received the following email from Apple:

> Starting in the first week of July,
>   apps that meet the following criteria
>   are required to comply with French
>   Encryption Laws/Regulations if you
>   intend to distribute your app in
>   France.
>
> This requirement applies to apps that
>   use, access, implement, or
>   incorporate:
>
> (a) any encryption algorithm that is
>   yet to be standardized by
>   international standard bodies such as
>   IEEE, IETF, ISO, ITU, ETSI, 3GPP, TIA,
>   etc. or not otherwise published; or
>
> (b) standard (e.g., AES, DES, 3DES,
>   RSA) encryption algorithm(s) instead
>   of or in addition to accessing or
>   using the encryption in iOS and/or Mac
>   OS X
>
> Apple will require you to upload a
>   copy of your approved French
>   declaration when you submit your app
>   to the App Store.
>
> Relevant French encryption regulations
>   can be found at:
>
> http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=LEGITEXT000005789847&dateTexte=#LEGIARTI000006421577
>
> http://www.ssi.gouv.fr/archive/fr/reglementation/regl_crypto.html
>
> http://www.ssi.gouv.fr/site_article195.html
>
> http://www.ssi.gouv.fr/site_article197.html
>
> Regards,
>
> Apple Export Compliance

I've had a hunt around the web, developer forums, etc, and cannot find one single English description of exactly what this means.

In my case (like many other people) I'm only using the standard encryption components provided in iOS - ie. https/SSL, AES, etc, I can't figure out if I need to do anything or not (beyond the USA encryption ERN that I've already completed). I'm worried it is going to delay submitting my next build though.

Does anyone have any further information/links (or speak French)?

Comment: Judging by the wording, I would say not (but I am not a lawyer, etc). "standard (e.g., AES, DES, 3DES, RSA) encryption algorithm(s) **instead of or in addition to** accessing or using the encryption in iOS and/or Mac OS X", but no mention of if you are exclusively using the encryption provided by iOS. Presumably Apple already has a permit for that.

Comment: Probably a better fit for Programmers SE, or the Apple Forums where you're more likely to get feedback from people who have had to deal with this.

Comment: Thanks for that! I've posted on the apple dev forums too, will report back I get a response there: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/109830

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I sent an email to the Apple Export Compliance department, and got a reply back:

> If your app only uses or accesses
>   encryption provided in iOS, you do not
>   need any further approvals from French
>   authorities.

So it seems for my case (using iOS's build in SSL/HTTPS/AES) I need to do nothing further.

Anyone finding the answer in the future might also want to check out this thread on the Apple dev forums in case any more information gets posted:

https://devforums.apple.com/thread/109830

Answer (score 0):

I've sent an email to Apple Export Compliance department.

My app is only using the built in https/SSL so it would seem likely that it does not need any authorization as the email states "***instead of or in addition to accessing or using the encryption in iOS***" but better wait for Apple's response.

If it turns out an authorization is needed I will simply pull my app from the French AppStore until proper authorization is obtained and on the next app update in AppStore I'm going to sign a declaration that states that my app will not be sold in France.

You could do the same, if you need authorization simply remove the app from France AppStore until you get it.